# Using task form fields to create items in another list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a workflow task that allows a user to enter some info when the workflow is running. These are Task Form Fields. I want to use the information the user enters in these in the task completion step (Create list item) but I am not sure how to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I edited my answer as I misread your question].

See the steps [in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kishore/archive/2012/01/15/updating-list-item-with-task-form-custom-field-in-sharepoint-approval-2010-workflow.aspx)

Basically, you first need to declare a Variable.
Then, inside your Task, in Change the behaviour of a single task, you assign the value of your Task Field to this variable and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: It was "Task Form Fields" I wanted to access. I was using "Change the behavious of the overall task process" when i should have used "Change the behavious of a single task"

Comment: Your edit was when i was answering my own question. Yep thats it.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a task, there is an option "Change the behaviour of the overall task process" and in that "When the Task Process Completes". I guess this is if many tasks exist so doesnt allow access to individual task fields. When using "Change the behaviour of a single task" and in that "When a Task Complete" I can access the current task fields.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kishore/archive/2012/01/15/updating-list-item-with-task-form-custom-field-in-sharepoint-approval-2010-workflow.aspx